# Problems with ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I have a very simple grammar file, which looks like this:

```
grammar Wort;

// Parser Rules:
word
    :   ANY_WORD EOF
    ;

// Lexer Rules:
ANY_WORD
    : SMALL_WORD | CAPITAL_WORD
    ;
SMALL_WORD 
    : SMALL_LETTER (SMALL_LETTER)+
    ;
CAPITAL_WORD 
    : CAPITAL_LETTER (SMALL_LETTER)+
    ;
fragment SMALL_LETTER
    : ('a'..'z')
    ;
fragment CAPITAL_LETTER
    : ('A'..'Z')
    ;
```

If i try to parse the input "Hello", everything is OK, BUT if if modify my grammar file like this:

```
...

// Parser Rules:
word
    :   CAPITAL_WORD EOF
    ;

...
```

the input "Hello" is no longer recognized as a valid input. Can anybody explain, what is going wrong?

Thanx, Lars

Comment: `ANY_WORD` should be a parser rule.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has to do with precedence in the lexer grammar. Because `ANY_WORD` is listed before `CAPITAL_WORD`, it is given higher precedence. The lexer will identify `Hello` as a `CAPITAL_WORD`, but since an `ANY_WORD` can be just a `CAPITAL_WORD`, and the lexer is set up to prefer `ANY_WORD`, it will output the token `ANY_WORD`. The parser acts on the output of the lexer, and since `ANY_WORD` `EOF` doesn't match any of its rules, the parse fails.

You can make the lexer behave differently by moving `CAPITAL_WORD` above `ANY_WORD` in the grammar, but that will create the opposite problem -- capitalized words will never lex as `ANY_WORD`s. The best thing to do is probably what [Mephy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3614521/mephy) suggested -- make `ANY_WORD` a parser rule.